# Ignore a route for access checking in Laravel 5 using Entrust Package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm using Entrust Laravel Package and it is working fine but there's a problem.

I want to show a login form to admin using the below controller

```
Route::get('/admin/login', array('as' => 'admin_login', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminAccessController@getLogin'));
```

How do I tell Entrust to 'disable' access control for some routes like "admin/login"?

```
Entrust::routeNeedsRole('admin/*', 'owner',dd(
    "Access Denied!"
));
```

Comment: Wait.. what do you mean? The `routeNeedsRole` method do exactly that what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like that..
([Documentation](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust#route-filter))

```
Route::filter('admin', function()
{
    // check the current user
    if (!Entrust::hasRole('admin')) {
        App::abort(403);
    }
});

// only admin will have access to routes within admin/login
Route::when('admin/login', 'admin');
```

Comment: Thanks but I know this. is there no other way just using Entrust routes?

Comment: thanks! it worked! so filters still exists in Laravel 5!